# How to use Regex to split sql script having GO statements in it?

Tags: sql, regex

I am trying to use .NET SQL client library to parse sql script that has GO statements in it. GO is only supported by osql, sqlcmd and SSMS as I understand it and is not supported by .NET SQL client library. I cannot use .NET SMO either. So the only remaining option I have is to parse the script and split it into groups of SQL strings without the GO in them, and execute one at a time. I would appreciate help with correct way of doing this with Regex. In particular, I'm looking to solve the following.

Let's say I have a SQL script as follows:

```
update tbl1
set col1 = "
GO right and then left
"
where col1 is null

/*
GO statement is not in TSQL
*/

  GO

select '
GO left and another left
'

GO --break up the batch

insert into tbl2 (col1)
values ('
GO
')

GO
```

I need to Regex to give me an array containing 3 string items as follows (after correctly identifying the 3 GO statements and removing them)

## array item 1

```
update tbl1
set col1 = "
GO right and then left
"
where col1 is null

/*
GO statement is not in TSQL
*/
```

## array item 2

```
select '
GO left and another left
'
```

## array item 3

```
insert into tbl2 (col1)
values ('
GO
')
```

Comment: Does [Regex.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx) do what you want? Then the regex might be as simple as `^GO$`.

Comment: It's not that simple.  He needs to add to the regex to check that there's whitespace either side, otherwise he could have a table called DeadGoannas or something, and it will match.

Comment: Even then it's not that simple. You don't want to perform a split for a *GO* within a string, such as in his "array item 2" example.

Comment: You need a parser. This is not a problem over a regular grammar/alphabet. It can be a simple parser. You just need to keep track of when you're in a string or comment when you find "GO" (uppercase).

Comment: I guess I'm looking for the following rule for Regex to apply:
  
1. Find lines that begin on a newline followed by 0 or more white space followed by GO followed by 0 or more of any character.  

2. Each of above lines cannot be within \A. single quotes B. double quotes and C. within /(one or more *) and (one or more *)/ 

  I got this far:

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(SQLScript, @"\n\s*[GO].+"))
 Console.WriteLine(match.Value);

Output:

GO right and then left


GO statement is not in TSQL



  GO


GO left and another left



GO --break up the batch


GO



GO

Comment: @SamDevx did you ever solve this?